# View is not display proper in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I make a view in storyboard with one view only. It looks good in Xcode but when I am trying to run the app in the device then it does not look good.

see below image in iPhone5C:
[image]

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks**

Comment: show ur xcode storyboard screen.

Comment: You need to add device related splash screen. like if you want to run in iPhone 4s: 640*960 if iPhone 5,5c,5s: 640*1136 iPhone 6 : 750*1334 and for iPhone 6+ 1242*2208 in image assets under (LaunchImage). check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268470/iphone-6-plus-screen-size/27268739#27268739)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You are using Xcode 6.x then You have to add a splash screen for all screen sizes,Do it with Images.xcassets.I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please Select Proper iPhone Retina Size while designing. 
Also use 1x, 2x and 3x size images with iPhone 4,5,6 respectively.

Set images With 1x, 2x and 3x sizes. it will solve your problem.