# How to set custom size for UIActivityViewController modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` for social sharing in my app, for iPhone `UIActivityViewController` modal is being used like this:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need to change the size of the modal that opens up, please help.

I tried:

```
activityController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(activityController.preferredContentSize.width/4, 250);
```

But this does not work and the size of the modal remains same.
I should be able to specify the size of the modal that opens on my app for iPhones.

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshots, the icons are appearing quite big, they do not appear this way in a few other apps that I checked. I need to tweak the size of the view and icons displayed inside it

Comment: My app sscreenhost, here the icon sizes appear quite big:                                 https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/jjm.so/myscreen1.jpg

Comment: Looked at fast company app, the icon sizes appear smaller and this is the icon size and window size am trying to achieve for my share screen:           https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/jjm.so/refscreen.jpg

Comment: Any suggestings on how to tweak the share screen and icon sizes will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app isn't enable the correct scale on your device. (Ex: The iphone 6s plus should get scale value:3) You can check your setting. (ref: [iPhone 6 (Plus) screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268470/iphone-6-plus-screen-size))

Answer (score -1):

Perform affine transformation on the activity's indicator view:

```
yourActivityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
[self addSubview:yourActivityIndicator];
```

Comment: I am using UIActivityViewController for share feature in my app

Comment: Sorry, though the question was about the activity indicator.