# never seen 375x667 points for 6p/6sp mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a project adapt to iPhone4s/5/5s/5c/6/6s/7/8/6p/6sp/7p/8p/x.
I use the code below to read the size in points

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

it will return

```
320x480 iPhone 4s
320x568 iPhone 5/5s/5c/6/6s/7/8/6p/6sp/7p/8p
375x812 iPhone x
```

but as I know

for 6/7/8 should be

```
375x667
```

for 6p/6sp/7p/8p should be

```
414x736
```

I have set Retina 4.7 5.5 LaunchImage in Image.xcassets file

Just wonder if there are resolution requirement for 4.7 5.5 LaunchImage ?

Comment: see this once may be its help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x/46192822#46192822

Comment: thanks, but this is a different question

Comment: could you maybe share your project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268470/iphone-6-plus-screen-size this answered my question